# Is there a way to flatten a .Net ILookup<TKey, TElement> into a List<TElement>?

Tags: .net, ilookup

Is there a quick way to get a flattened `List<TElement>` from an `ILookup<TKey, TElement>` that was created from the `IEnumerable<TElement>` extension?

---

Updated with example

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
var lookup = list.ToLookup(key => key);
list = lookup.?? // How to convert the lookup back to the list
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
lookup.SelectMany( x => x ).ToList()
```

The transformation to `ILookup` and back again will have most likely changed the order, however.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after. For `Dictionary<>` to `List<>`

```
List<TElement> list iLookUp.Values.ToList<TElement>();
```

from `List<>` to `Dictionary<>`

```
var dict = list.Cast<TElement>().ToDictionary(t => t.Id, t => t.Description);
```

Comment: Thanks, not quite what I am looking for though. I have updated the question for clarity

Comment: It does not look like `ILookup` has a `Values` property.